# Is there a way to store thresholding operation output in Eigen (C++)?

Tags: c++, eigen

In MATLAB, you can create a binary matrix B by thresholding a matrix A as follows:

```
B = A > threshold
```

Where `threshold` is some value. In Eigen for C++, I have been able see similar results, but have faced an inability to assign the output. That is, given

```
MatrixXd M =
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

(I know that's not proper initialization but for the sake of the question, go with it)

```
cout << (M < 1)
```

produces

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

but

```
MatrixXd N = M < 1;
```

and

```
M = M < 1;
```

both give build errors.

Can someone please explain the correct way to save the binary output of this threshold to a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator<` is defined only in the *array* world, so you have to use `.array()` to see your `MatrixXd` as an `ArrayXXd` (no copy here), and then the result is a array of boolean, so if you want double, then you have to cast explicitly:

```
MatrixXd M(3,3);
M << 0, 1, 2,
     0, 1, 2,
     0, 1, 2;
MatrixXb Rb = (M.array() < 0.5);                 // result as a matrix of bool
MatrixXd Rd = (M.array() < 0.5).cast<double>();  // result as a matrix of double
```

Comment: One thing to point out is I don't believe there's a gobal typedef for MatrixXb, so it's necessary to do it oneself: `typedef Matrix<bool, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXb;`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your results using `std::cout << (M < 1)` and also cannot find this documented anywhere.

You can create a new matrix from an existing one by applying a unary function to each element by using the `unaryExpr` member function.  Using C++11 lambda expressions, this becomes really straight forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int
main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd m1(4, 3);
  m1.setRandom();
  Eigen::MatrixXd m2 = m1.unaryExpr([](double d){ return d < 0.5; });
  std::cout << m1 << "\n\n" << m2 << "\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
  0.680375   0.823295  -0.444451
 -0.211234  -0.604897    0.10794
  0.566198  -0.329554 -0.0452059
   0.59688   0.536459   0.257742

0 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

Not that I know exactly why you would like to have the results of a boolean operation stored in a real matrix, but you can certainly do it.  Also, you should generally avoid to explicitly convert the result of a matrix expression to a `MatrixXd` (or any other explicit type) since every time you do that, you set a cut in Eigen's powerful expression template chaining.  In C++11, use `auto` a lot unless you really need eager evaluation / type conversion.

Comment: You know what? I think it may have been because I was using ArrayXXd. If you convert MatrixXd to ArrayXXd you should see my cout results. As for storing in a real matrix, I guess it can be a boolean. And to the last piece: I don't think I understand what you mean about explicit conversion. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @marcman In Eigen, the result type of `MatrixXd + MatrixXd` is *not* `MatrixXd` but some special expression template that is implicitly convertible to `MatrixXd`.  But this conversion is done lazily.  This has the benefit that, if you use the result of the previous expression in another expression, instead of looping over the matrix elements twice, the Eigen core is able to fuse these operations into a single, more cache efficient, loop.